# Python function make parameter mandatory if another parameter is passed

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I have a function in Python as

```
def myfunc(a, b=None, c=None):
    my code here
```

Is there a way to ensure that if the user passes the value of the parameter `b` it is necessary to pass the parameter `c` to `myfunc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple `if` condition in your function. See the code below:

```py
def myfunc(a, b=None, c=None):
    if c is not None and b is None:
        raise ValueError("Value of b must be passed if value of c is passed")
    your code here
```

Comment: what if user has provided `None` as third argument, this will fail

Comment: The assumption here is that passing `None` is equivalent to not passing anything since `None` is the default value here.

Comment: None is assumed as default value not no value is passed

Answer (score 1):

Not in any built in way. Check it yourself:

```py
def myfunc(a, b=None, c=None):
    if b is not None and c is None:
        raise ValueError("Invalid arguments")
    # ...
```

Comment: what if user has provided `None` as third argument, this will fail

Comment: @sahasrara62 If you supply a value that is the same as a default value, it's assumed you wanted whatever behavior the default value implies.

Comment: it can be one of the case where c value passed in `None`  in that sense for me atleast this solution doesn't make any sense

Comment: @sahasrara62 For a python function defined as `def func(a=None)`, calling it with either `func()`, `func(None)`, or `func(a=None)`, are all expected to have the same behavior.